# Does declaring variables in class vs subroutine impact memory/cpu usage in application processing every 5 seconds 24/7 in .net?

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I will be capturing a new image every 5 seconds from a .net executable that I will run on the server 24/7. So I am trying to create the most stable code that will use the least amount of memory and cpu as possible. I will be running multiple instances of this as well.

So should I declare the object as part of the class as below?

```
Public Class ImageProcessForm

    Dim MyImageObj as new MultiImageObj

    ‘Call ProcessImage() every 5 seconds via timer

    Private Sub ProcessImage ()

        MyImageObj.Image = ImageFromStream()
        MyImageObj.ResizeMedia()
        MyImageObj.AddCaption(“My Caption”)
        MyImageObj.Save(MyLocation)

    End Sub
```

Or should the MutliImageObj be created and destroyed each time in the subroutine?

```
Public Class ImageProcessForm

    ‘Call ProcessImage() every 5 seconds via timer

    Private Sub ProcessImage ()

        Using MyImageObj as new MultiImageObj
            MyImageObj.Image = ImageFromStream()
            MyImageObj.ResizeMedia()
            MyImageObj.AddCaption(“My Caption”)
            MyImageObj.Save(MyLocation)
        End using  ‘MyImageObj disposed of

End Sub
```

Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Putting it in the class means that during the 5 minutes of idle time, the object will still occupy memory. You can null it out when done, or use a local.

Comment: Actually I said 5 seconds, does this change your point of view then?

Comment: Answer still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is interesting...

Put the routine in a Class and Disposing it (as you do with Using - End Using) may require .NET to:

```
1- Instance the Class, which will require RAM and CPU;
2- RAM will be busy until Garbage Collector decide to *really* clean RAM
3- It may occurr after 5 seconds or even after some minutes.
```

So, during a certain time, you will have more RAM than really needed and some CPU tasks...

I´m not considering neither the usage of ThreadPool or BackGroundWorker, ok?

I believe utilize it as a routine will consume LESS RAM (since it will be loaded one time) and CPU (since it will be cached by system).

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify: _I´m not considering neither the usage of ThreadPool or BackGroundWorker, ok?_

Comment: Sure. A BackgroundThread is efficient to free resources after its end and cease run immediately when the main thread ends - ans also, it can be cancelled at any point. The ThreadPool also is really efficient to allocate resources and free them since is the .NET that manage it in a multithread environment (like a routine called on each 5 seconds). If they will utilize more/less resources (it´s expected no differences between a routine), it´s a case of test.

Comment: I ran some tests, and can confirm that using the routine instead does use about 10% less memory per process. In both cases CPU was only used briefly during the image capture then it would go back to zero.